# Pass value from each iteration to a function Power Query (in Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a standard report file in Power BI and need to add more rows/records regularly. There are about 8 attributes for every records. The other 9 attributes will be filled (or not filled), which depend on Type of records. 
I used **Table.InsertRows** but could not find a way to pass value (runs from 0 to 10) to variable x in that function. x means the serial number of records in the new data file. My idea is to add the first row of new data to the standard file, and then the 2nd, 3rd row etc.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\uic30477\Desktop\Musterfile test.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Type", type text}, {"General column1", Int64.Type}, {"General column2", Int64.Type}, {"General column3", Int64.Type}, {"General column4", Int64.Type}, {"General column5", Int64.Type}, {"General column6", Int64.Type}, {"General column7", Int64.Type}, {"General column8", Int64.Type}, {"CDF column1", Int64.Type}, {"CDF column2", Int64.Type}, {"CDF column3", Int64.Type}, {"Budget column1", Int64.Type}, {"Budget column2", Int64.Type}, {"Budget column3", Int64.Type}, {"Budget column4", Int64.Type}, {"Deliveries column1", Int64.Type}, {"Deliveries column2", Int64.Type}}),
    Custom1 = List.Generate(
        () => [x=0],
        each [x]<=10,
        each [x=[x]+1]
    ),
    Table.InsertRows(#"Changed Type", 7, {[Type = #"Newdata"{x}[Type], General column1 = #"Newdata"{x}[General column1], General column2 = #"Newdata"{x}[General column2], General column3 = #"Newdata"{x}[General column3], General column4 = #"Newdata"{x}[General column4], General column5 = #"Newdata"{x}[General column5], General column6 = #"Newdata"{x}[General column6], General column7 = #"Newdata"{x}[General column7], General column8 = #"Newdata"{x}[General column8], CDF column1 = #"Newdata"{x}[CDF column1], CDF column2 = #"Newdata"{x}[CDF column2], CDF column3 = #"Newdata"{x}[CDF column3], Budget column1 = #"Newdata"{x}[Budget column1], Budget column2 = #"Newdata"{x}[Budget column2], Budget column3 = #"Newdata"{x}[Budget column3], Budget column4 = #"Newdata"{x}[Budget column4], Deliveries column1 = #"Newdata"{x}[Deliveries column1], Deliveries column2 = #"Newdata"{x}[Deliveries column2]]})
in
    Custom1
```

I am totally new in this language. Any suggestion or another way to insert new records would be very useful to me.
Thank you!

Comment: It's difficult to visualise what you're starting with and what you want to end up with. If I'm reading the code and question correctly, it seems like you just want to append rows from table `#"Newdata"` to the table ``#"Changed Type"`. If so, have a look at `Table.Combine` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-combine). It expects a `list` of `tables`. You could use `Table.ColumnNames`, `Table.SelectColumns` and `Table.Combine` together to restrict which columns are appended.

Comment: When you refresh your dataset, your tables in PowerBI will be entirely reloaded.  The place to add your new rows is in the excel file -- and then all of the data will be pulled into PowerBI on the next refresh.  Out of curiosity, how many 'types' of rows do you need to load?  you might want to consider loading each 'type' of row into it's own table.  A model were rows in a single table somehow represent different kinds of objects will usually add lots of complexity down the road.

Comment: @chillin thank you! To summary the problem: I have 4 columns, first column is Type (A, B or C), then column A, B and C respectively. If the new record has Type A, then column A will be filled with x, and empty by column B and column C. However, each new dataset will have about more than 200,000 rows/records and I cannot find a way to automatically add them to the standard file with your recommended functions.

Comment: @RyanB. Thank you. I have to add about 200,000 rows to the standard file daily. So I want to write a code which can help to add automatically new rows (from the new dataset), but the value in every column will be added or not depends on value of one certain column. For example, if new row has type Deliveries, only columns represent meaning of Deliveries will be filled. Otherwise they will be in blank.